# how to make sure to never get ora-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column?

Tags: oracle

I'm doing a division for each record and updating a certain column with the result

so my sql looks something like this

```
update table1 set frequency = num/denom where id>XXX
```

my frequency data type is number(10,10)

Based on https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT1838

First, I'm not even sure why I get this data because the answer will always be 0.XXX, so giving 10 before the comma would be a plenty. Then the 10 after the comma should be okay too because it will truncate if the answer is bigger.

Comment: What happens if you run `SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE num/denom >=1`?

Comment: Slight correction to your last sentence. Oracle won't truncate the number, it will round it. Slight difference at your level of scale (10) but makes a big difference with only one or two decimal points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NUMBER(10, 10)` means 10 digits and a scale of 10.

That means you have 10 digits right of the decimal point which means **no** digit left of it.

So having the table

```
CREATE TABLE t
(
   test   NUMBER (10, 10)
);
```

`insert into t values (0.9999999999);` will work, while

`insert into t values (0.99999999999);`will fail because the value is rounded up to 1.

So if `num/denom` is 1 or even larger you will get `ORA-01438: value larger than specified precision allowed for this column`.

But you will also get this error, if `num/denom` is larger then 0.99999999995 as oracle tries to round it to 1.

Comment: so will number(11,10) make sure I'll never get this error? I'm sure it will never be larger than 1 because the numerator is always equal or less than the denominator.

Comment: @Andy: It will. Number(11,10) allows you to store one digit left of the decimal point, which means 1.9999999999 ist the largest value you're able to store.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, let me get this confusion around the precision and scale cleared out. According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#CNCPT313), it is stated:

> For numeric columns, you can specify the column as:
>
> column_name NUMBER
>
> Optionally, you can also specify a precision
>   (total number of digits) and scale (number of digits to the right of
>   the decimal point):
>
> column_name NUMBER (precision, scale)

In your case:

```
frequency NUMBER(10,10)
```

This means, that the total number of digits is 10 and this means that the column can accommodate values from:

```
0.0000000001
```

to:

```
9999999999
```

This includes Integers up to 9999999999 (10 nines) and floats from 0.0000000001 (9 zeroes and a 1 at the end).

Now that we know this, let's proceed to the problem..
You need this query to never fail with `ORA-01438`:

```
update table1 set frequency = num/denom where id>XXX;
```

You can do the following check, on update time:

```
update table1
   set frequency = CASE LENGTH(TRUNC(num/denom)) >=10
                     THEN TRUNC(num/denom, 10)
                   ELSE
                     ROUND(num/denom), 10 - LENGTH(TRUNC(num/denom))) --TRUNC
                   END
 where id>XXX;
```

What this would do is check:
1. If the whole part of the division is more than or equal to 10; in that case, return only the first 10 digits (`TRUNCATE`).
2. If the whole part is less than 10; in that case `ROUND` the result to "`10 - LENGTH_OF_WHOLE_PART`" decimal places, but still within the precision of 10, which is the one of the column.

*Note: The `ROUND` above will actually `ROUND` the result, giving you an inaccurate value. If you need to get a raw truncation of the result, use `TRUNCATE` instead of `ROUND` above!

Cheers

Comment: NUMBER(10, 10) means 10 digits and a scale of 10. That means you have 10 digits right of the decimal point which means no digit left of it. So `insert into t values (0.9999999999);`will work, while `insert into t values (0.99999999999);`will fail because it's rounded up to 1